# Dealing with huge table - 100M+ rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have table with around 100 million rows and it is only getting larger, as table is queried pretty frequently I have to come up with some solution to optimise this.

Firstly here is **the model**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TreningExercises](
[TreningExerciseId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[NumberOfRepsForExercise] [int] NOT NULL,
[CycleNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[TreningId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ExerciseId] [int] NOT NULL,
[RoutineExerciseId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL)
```

Here is Trening table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trenings](
[TreningId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[DateTimeWhenTreningCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Score] [int] NOT NULL,
[NumberOfFinishedCycles] [int] NOT NULL,
[PercentageOfCompleteness] [int] NOT NULL,
[IsFake] [bit] NOT NULL,
[IsPrivate] [bit] NOT NULL,
[UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[AllRoutinesId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)
```

**Indexes** (other than PK which are clustered):

TreningExercises:

1. TreningId (also FK)
2. ExerciseId (also FK)

Trenings:

1. UserId (also FK)
2. AllRoutinesId (also FK)
3. Score
4. DateTimeWhenTreningCreated (ordered by DateTimeWhenTreningCreated DESC)

And here is the example of the **most commonly executed query**:

```
DECLARE @userId VARCHAR(40)
,@exerciseId INT;

SELECT TOP (1) R.[TreningExerciseId] AS [TreningExerciseId]
    ,R.[NumberOfRepsForExercise] AS [NumberOfRepsForExercise]
    ,R.[TreningId] AS [TreningId]
    ,R.[ExerciseId] AS [ExerciseId]
    ,R.[RoutineExerciseId] AS [RoutineExerciseId]
    ,R.[DateTimeWhenTreningCreated] AS [DateTimeWhenTreningCreated]
FROM (
    SELECT TE.[TreningExerciseId] AS [TreningExerciseId]
        ,TE.[NumberOfRepsForExercise] AS [NumberOfRepsForExercise]
        ,TE.[TreningId] AS [TreningId]
        ,TE.[ExerciseId] AS [ExerciseId]
        ,TE.[RoutineExerciseId] AS [RoutineExerciseId]
        ,T.[DateTimeWhenTreningCreated] AS [DateTimeWhenTreningCreated]
    FROM [dbo].[TreningExercises] AS TE
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Trenings] AS T ON TE.[TreningId] = T.[TreningId]
    WHERE (T.[UserId] = @userId)
        AND (TE.[ExerciseId] = @exerciseId)
    ) AS R
ORDER BY R.[DateTimeWhenTreningCreated] DESC
```

**Execution plan:** [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyziStTLX)

Please accept my apologies if it is bit unreadable or unoptimised, it was generated by ORM (Entity Framework), I just edited it a bit.

According to Azure's SQL Analytics tool this query has the most impact on my DB and even though it usually doesn't take too long to execute,  from time to time there are spikes in DB I/O due to it.

Also there is a bit business logic involved in this, to simplify it: 99% of the time I need data which is less then a year old.
What are my best options regarding querying and table size?

My thoughts on querying, either:

1. Create indexed view OR
2. Add Date and UserId fields to the TreningExerciseId table OR
3. Some option that I haven't thought of :)

Regarding table size, either:

1. Partition table (probably by date) OR
2. Move most of the data (or all of it) to some NoSQL key-value store OR
3. Some option that I haven't thought of :)

What are your thoughts about these problems, how should I approach solving them?

Comment: Forget about indexed views - just start with a basic index! You might want to post the other table (Trenings), the indexes you have on the table, and possibly the query plan. PS should that be spelt "Training"??

Comment: The table has no NC indexes or primary key? I agree with @Nick.McDermaid that's probably the place to start.

Comment: Can you post an execution plan to this site:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/  And **edit your question** to add the link?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, Jacob H, MJH:  I have updated my question with list of indexes, Trening table and execution plan :)

Comment: Most obvious thing at this stage is use INT instead of Uniqueidentifier unless you have a reason for it.

Comment: When using C# and EF dealing with Guid (Uniqueidentifier) is much easier if you want to create ID-s by yourself, that's why I've gone with this option, nevertheless I am not sure how helpful conversion to INTs will be when table grows to 500M / 1T rows, which I suspect will happen within a year

Comment: Can you add the definition of the index "ix_TreninID" to your question please?

Comment: @MJH I have dropped the index (the query is still executing) and I will create it again while add new columns as you suggested in your answer - It will take a wile for everything to finish

Answer (score 2):

If you add the following columns to the index "ix_TreninID":

- NoOfRepsForExecercise
- ExerciseID
- RoutineExerciseID

That will make the index a "covering index" and eliminate the need for the lookup which is taking 95% of the plan.

Give it a go, and post back.

Comment: Here is new execution plan :) https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1nbXsaU7

Comment: For the time being everything is fine, but as I said before, query is fast for the most of the time, expect there are spike sometimes which slow whole DB down. So I'll have to wait to see if there are spikes again - Monday is when we have most of the traffic.

Comment: Also about number of rows, as I said in my question, the table will only grow, what is best strategy to deal with this? Should I just leave it as it is until it hits for example 1T rows (and then what) or do you have some suggestion ?

Comment: If it aint broke then don't try to fix it.

Comment: Well I would not say that it is not broken, I still get pikes due to it, as you can see in this [image](https://imgur.com/a/09x3zVy) I still get spikes in DB consumption, and I would very much like to fix this :)